# What is the scope of the environment that the closure holds?

Tags: go, garbage-collection, closures

I imitated the online tutorial on closures and wrote the following code.

```
func foo1() func() {
    xValue := 1
    x := &xValue
    defer func() {
        xValue = 2
    }()
    return func() {
        *x = *x + 1
        fmt.Printf("foo1 val = %d\n", *x)
    }
}

func main() {

    f1 := foo1()
    f1()
    f1()
    f1()
}
```

I am confused that after the exection of `f1 := foo1()`, the variable `xValue` seems like should be recycled, so the use of `*x` should be wrong, but the above code has no errors and is executed fined, which gives the output

```
foo1 val = 3
foo1 val = 4
foo1 val = 5
```

So I wonder if the closure holds the value of the pointer in addition to the pointer itself or is the garbage collection mechanism of the Go language causing xValue to not be deleted?

Comment: The guarantee of garbage collection is straightforward: as long as a value is reachable, it is not eligible for collection. `xValue` is reachable (via the pointer `x`), so it is not eligible for collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Go, a closure takes a reference to (an address of) any variable it closes over. To cite [the language reference](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Function_literals):

> Function literals are closures: they may refer to variables defined in a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as long as they are accessible.

Hence, in your example:

1. `f1 := foo1()`

   1. Brings the `xValue` variable into existence (the compiler will likely allocate it on the heap). It will start out with the zero value for its type, 0.
   2. Brings the variable `x` into existence and assigns it the address of `xValue`.
   3. The `defer`-red closure runs and assigns to `xValue` the value 2.
   4. Returns a closure which closes over the variable `x`.

   The latter point may be a bit tricky: since the returned closure references the variable `x`, the compiler guarantees that variable exists even after `foo` returned. Since `x` contains an address of (and hence a live reference to) `xValue`, that one still exists, too, and cannot be garbage-collected.
   Using the same escape analysis approach, the compiler guarantees `xValue` survives the return from the function it was declared in.
2. You execute the returned closure which modifies `xValue` via the pointer to it–no magic happens here. The other two calls do the same.

All-in-all, maybe you got tripped by your knowledge of C++, where any variable declared in a function ceases to exist once the control is returned from that function, and hence any references to it existing outside of that function become invalid. In Go, that is not the case: the language is explicitly defined as safe in this regard: the compiler makes sure any variable has suitable allocation to survive the function call it was created in if a reference to it is returned (or otherwise communicated) from that function call to the outside world.

Answer (score 3):

[Spec: Function literals:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Function_literals)

> Function literals are *closures*: they may refer to variables defined in a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as long as they are accessible.

The `x` and `xValue` variables created in `foo1()` and referred to by the returned function literal will survive as long as the returned function value is accessible.